# Creating multiple files in one function but they are overwriting each other. PHP

Tags: php

I am in the process of creating a section of a webpage where a user can upload a photo then manipulate the attributes of said picture, title, caption, etc. My questions comes as this: I have an edit picture function that I create a new caption file in by

```
//create new file
$file = fopen($newinfofile,"w");

//write to file
fwrite($file,$caption);

//close the file
fclose($file);
```

newinfofile being the files name.

I also create a new title file the same way but with different names

```
//create new file for title
$file2 = fopen($newinfofile2,"w");

//write to file for title
fwrite($file2,$newtitle);   

//close the file for title
fclose($file2);
```

Later I echo the contents of each file but my problem is that they are echoing the same thing, if I reverse the order and create my title file first they both echo caption info instead.

So in PHP can you not create and write to two files within the same function? Perhaps I am mis-understanding something but I am unsure as to what.

**Edit "sharing the entire function"**

```
//edit file name, picture title, picture caption

function EditRecord($dir, $collection,$picture,$newname,$newtitle,$caption)
{

    //set the picture paths

    $picpath = $dir . $collection . "/" . $picture;
    $newpicpath = $dir . $collection . "/" . $newname;

    //set name of file for caption info by changing out JPG for PHP
    $infofile = $dir . "Info/" . str_replace("jpg","php", $picture);
    $newinfofile = $dir . "Info/" . str_replace("jpg","php", $newname);

    //set name of file for title info by changing out JPG for PHP
    $infofile2 = $dir . "Info/" . str_replace("jpg","php", $picture);
    $newinfofile2 = $dir . "Info/" . str_replace("jpg","php", $newname);

    //replace \r with <br>
    $caption = str_replace("\r","<br>", $caption);

    //rename picture JPG file
    rename($picpath, $newpicpath);

    //rename info PHP file
    rename($infofile, $newinfofile);

    //rename 2nd info php file for title
    rename($infofile2, $newinfofile2);

    //create new file
    $file = fopen($newinfofile,"w");

    //write to file
    fwrite($file,$caption);

    //close the file
    fclose($file);  

    //create new file for title
    $file2 = fopen($newinfofile2,"w");

    //write to file for title
    fwrite($file2,$newtitle);   

    //close the file for title
    fclose($file2); 
}
```

Comment: You really should learn about databases. Using files for all that is nothing that will scale.

Comment: Can you share the full function please?

Comment: About the specific question at hand: you overwrite the contents of that file each time you open and write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two filesnames you create are exactly the same.

`$newinfofile = $dir . "Info/" . str_replace("jpg","php", $newname);`

`$newinfofile2 = $dir . "Info/" . str_replace("jpg","php", $newname);`

both variables will contain the same filename and so write to the same file, consequently overwriting.

Comment: Thank you, my understanding was that while the nameing of those were the same, becuase they had different variable names they would be treated different, but you are correct. Still learning!

Answer (score 0):

You actually generate same file names in `$newinfofile` and `$newinfofile2`:

```
//set name of file for caption info by changing out JPG for PHP
$infofile = $dir . "Info/" . str_replace("jpg","php", $picture);
$newinfofile = $dir . "Info/" . str_replace("jpg","php", $newname);
```

is same as

```
//set name of file for title info by changing out JPG for PHP
$infofile2 = $dir . "Info/" . str_replace("jpg","php", $picture);
$newinfofile2 = $dir . "Info/" . str_replace("jpg","php", $newname);
```

Comment: Thank you, my understanding was that while the nameing of those were the same, becuase they had different variable names they would be treated different, but you are correct. Still learning!